# only show the updated values in combo box after another combo box selection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox, items

When I select the item from combo box 1 it show the items in combo box two.

And when I select another item from combo box 1 it show both the items of previous result and new result in combo box 2

I just want to show only the new items in combo box 2. As I select the items from combo box 1 Combo box 2 should be updated and remove previous items.

```
private void cb_oname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Pizza Mania;Integrated Security=True");
    {
        SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Product_category FROM Product2 where Product_Name='"+cb_oname.SelectedItem+"'", sqlConnection);
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqlrdr = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlrdr.Read())
            {
                cb_ocat.Items.add(sqlrdr["Product_category"].ToString());
                cb_ocat.Update();
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve what i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the item at the selectedindex from the Items collection of the first combo.

Notice that I have also changed your code to use the correct using statement around disposable objects and a parameter instead of your very dangerous string concatenation

```
private void cb_oname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Safety check, SelectedIndexChanged is called also when there is
    // no item selected (see later)
    if(cb_oname.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return;

    using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(.....))
    using(SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Product_category 
                     FROM Product2 WHERE Product_Name=@name", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cb_oname.SelectedItem;

        using(SqlDataReader sqlrdr = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Clear the previous items list
            cb_ocat.Items.Clear(); 
            while (sqlrdr.Read())
                cb_ocat.Items.Add(sqlrdr["Product_category"].ToString());
        }
    }
    // Remove from the Items collection, but it is not enough
    cb_oname.Items.RemoveAt(cb_oname.SelectedIndex);
    // Set the selectedindex to -1 so the current text in the combo is reset        
    cb_oname.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: getting error on sqlconnection.open that it does not exist in the current context!!

Comment: getting error on sqlcmd2.parameters that it doesnot exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry my mistake, removing the semicolons at the end of the  using

Comment: the semi colons in the end of the using statements should be removed ??

Comment: i removed them but still getting error that cannot initialize type system.data.sqlclient with a collection initializer because it does not implement system.coll.ienumerable

Comment: Fixed again, missing the second close parenthesys on the secon using

Comment: the starting bracket before sqlconnection.open()

Comment: and getting syntax error on sqlconn.open(); that ', ' expected!!

Comment: still getting error that cannot initialize type system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand with a collection initializer because it does not implement system.coll.IEnumerable

Comment: I can't see any error now. Should be something really simple.... could you [edit] your question adding (not replacing) you current code ?

Comment: i removes all the Using statements and now my code is going perfect!!

Comment: steve just tell me how to use using statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107396/discussion-between-steve-and-aly-goreja).